# warnen oder vorwarnen

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "warnen" und "vorwarnen"?

Um genauer zu sein, im Großen und Ganzen verstehe ich das Verb "warnen", aber "vorwarnen" nicht.

Ich muss zugeben, dass mir "vorwarnen" ein bisschen redundant erscheint.

Comment: Das musst Du nicht zugeben, weil man es einerseits schon ahnt und andererseits daran nichts anrüchiges ist, das der Entschuldigung bedarf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In der Tat, rein semantisch gesehen ist *vorwarnen* redudant, da *warnen* ja auf jeden Fall *vor* einem Ereignis stattfinden muss (das also in der Zukunft liegt).

In der praktischen Sprache verwendet man *vorwarnen* trotzdem relativ häufig. Übrigens ohne einen *semantischen* Unterschied zwischen *warnen* und *vorwarnen*.

> a) Was, das Pferd hat Schnupfen? Hättest du mich doch vorgewarnt!
>
> b) Was, das Pferd hat Schnupfen? Hättest du mich doch gewarnt!

Beides heißt exakt das gleiche. Satz (a) käme aber eher in mündlicher Sprache vor, Satz (b) eher in schriftlicher.

In mündlicher Sprache fügt man bisweilen kurzen Wörtern irgend eine Silbe hinzu, um sie länger zu machen und um die Bedeutung klarer werden zu lassen. Das *vor* vor *warnen* hat so eine Funktion: Es macht das Wort länger, das heißt, die Aufmerksamkeit des Hörers wird länger daran haften bleiben. Und durch das zusätliche *vor* unterstreicht der Sprecher, dass es ihm wichtig gewesen wäre, von der Krankheit des Pferdes deutlich vorher zu erfahren (z.B: bevor er sich draufsetzt).

Ein Grund für die Wahl von *vorwarnen* oder *warnen* kann übrigens auch der Satzrhythmus sein.

Ein anderes Beispiel für eine solche *Unterstreichungssilbe* (wie ich das jetzt einmal nenne) ist

> *Den Briten wurde die EU-Mitgliedschaft aufoktroyiert.

Dieser Satz wird von gebildeten Personen für falsch gehalten (und nicht nur wegen des Inhalts): *Jemandem etwas oktroyieren* heißt  bereits *jemandem etwas aufzwingen*. Zu sagen, man *zwänge* jemandem etwas *aufauf* (*aufaufzwingen*) wäre albern. Jedoch erkennt die weniger gebildete Person beim *oktroyieren* nicht, dass das *auf* schon drinsteckt, darum hört man diese Wortverwendung recht häufig.

**Ergänzende Beobachtung**

Bei gängigen Verben mit Vorsilbe wird im Deutschen in bestimmten Satzbau-Situationen die Vorsilbe abgetrennt:

> Ich werde beim Stierkampf zusehen.  --- Ich sehe beim Stierkampf zu.
>
> Wir sollten die Suppe kurz aufkochen. --- Ich koche die Suppe kurz auf.

(Nicht jedoch in allen Fällen. *Wir sollten diese Dinge unterscheiden* --- *Wir unterscheiden diese Dinge*, und nicht etwa: *Wir scheiden diese Dinge unter.*)

Mit *vorwarnen* scheint mir, ist die Abtrennung der Vorsilbe (zwar technisch möglich, aber) nicht wirklich üblich. Man könnte zwar, aber man sagt nicht:

> *Ich warne dich vor.
>
> *Der Küstenwetterdienst warnte die Segelsportler vor, dass nachmittags Böen zu erwarten seien.

So etwas klingt - jedenfalls in meinen Ohren - holprig.

Ich würde das so deuten, dass *vorwarnen* kein vollgültiges präfigiertes Verb ist und dass das *vor* hier eben eher als eine *Unterstreichungsilbe* (ohne jedoch die volle syntaktische Funktion) anzusehen ist. (Meine persönliche Deutung. Ich weiß nicht, was die publizierte Philologie dazu sagt.)

Comment: Ich denke eher, dass eine zusätzliche Vorsilbe tendenziell eine Verstärkung der Bedeutung bewirkt. Und das ist nicht nur im Deutschen so: lateinisch _cadere_ und _decadere_, bspw. Aber es gibt zahlreiche Beispiele.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  War nicht dies das, was ich auch zu sagen versuchte, wenn auch nicht in der von Dir gemeisterten Kürze und Eleganz?

Comment: Kann sein, dass Du das sagen wolltest, es ist bei mir nicht so angekommen. :-) Du schreibst, dass die Verlängerung die Bedeutung *klarer* machen soll, darunter habe ich etwas anderes verstanden, als dass es die Bedeutung *verstärken* soll. Aber vielleicht habe ich dich da falsch verstanden.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Sicherlich kann man unterscheiden zwischen *eine Aussage klarer machen* und *eine Aussage verstärken*. Doch gibt es zwischen beidem auch eine große Zone der Überschneidung. Ich habe diese im Auge gehabt, du mehr die Sonderzonen.

Answer (score 2):

In den meisten Fällen werden *warnen* und *vorwarnen* synonym gebraucht, und die Vorsilbe *vor* ist dann in der Tat redundant.

Allerdings kann man jemanden warnen bevor etwas passiert, die Zeit das Unheil abzuwenden kann aber zu kurz sein. Dann ist m.E. nur noch "warnen" passend.

> Der Beifahrer warnte noch: "Ein Kind!". Doch da rummste es auch schon.

Außerdem kann eine Warnung zu unspezifisch sein, um als Vorwarnung bezeichnet werden zu können:

> Der Pfaffe warnte uns jede Woche, dass Wein, Weib und Gesang ins Verderben führen.

Auch hier passt **vorwarnen** nicht.

Außerdem erscheint mir *Vorwarnung* unpassend, wenn das Unheil gar nicht eintritt.

> Der Wetterbericht warnte vor Sturmböen, aber es kam nur zu mittleren Brisen.

Comment: Gut beobachtet, +1

Comment: Ich stimme zu, möchte aber präzisierend hinzufügen, dass der Unterschied gleichwohl weniger ein semantischer, mehr ein pragmatischer ist: In welchen Situationen verwendet man welches der beiden Verben? - Du würdest Dir auch schwer tun, dein Wetterbeispiel mit *vorwarnen* umzuformen, selbst wenn der Sturm dann richtig heftig wurde. Du würdest nie sagen: *Der Wetterbericht warnte vor Sturmböen **vor**, und diese wurden dann auch richtig heftig.* Du würdest trotzdem sagen: *Der Wetterbericht **warnte** vor Sturmböen, und in der Tat fegten diese dann Baum und Strauch aus der Landschaft*.

Comment: ... Allgemein gilt wohl: *vorwarnen* wird überhaupt nur in dieser Zusammenschreibung verwendet. Die Abspaltung der Vorsilbe, wie das bei vollgültigen Vorsilbenverben gängig ist, scheint bei *vorwarnen* nicht möglich zu sein. So gesehen ist *vorwarnen* kein vollgültig präfigiertes Verb. Und das ist wieder ein Argument für meine These, dass es sich hier nur um eine kommunikationspraktische Unterstreichungs-Vorsilbe handelt.

Comment: Gibt es denn ein Beispiel dafür, dass vorwarnen in einem Satz viel besser passt als warnen? Mir fällt spontan keines ein.

Comment: Ich habe diese Beispiele für "vorwarnen" gefunden. Aber ich weiß nicht, ob man nur mir "vorwarnen" benutzen kann.
z.B. Ich habe diese Fehler begangen, obwohl er mich vorgewarnt hat
z.B. Ich habe dich vorgewarnt, warum bist du so schnell gefahren?
z.B. Das Gerät warnt vor, wenn die Batterien leer werden.